# Google Now Accent Bug (Lollipop 5.0)

Tags: google-now, localization, bugs, 5.0-lollipop, google-voice-actions

I updated to Android 5.0 yesterday on my Nexus 5.

I am from the UK, hence I have my languages set to "English (UK)" where possible, including the voice of Google Now, which has the accent of an English woman.

After this update Google Now appears to be partially ignoring my language settings in relation to accent. If I ask it something that Google can answer, such as "How far away is the sun", it replies with an English accent, but if I ask it to do something specific to my phone, such as setting an alarm, it replies with the accent of an American woman.

Is this a bug, a weird feature or is there a fix?

Comment: Seems to be happening to me too, rather jarring at first.